# spring MVC RedirectView

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("login.htm"),"message","Your session has expired. Please login");

how do i get this message in login.jsp

<%request.getAttribute("message"); %>

${message}

any of above options didnt work

Answer (score 3):

I guess since you're redirecting the model will not be available (redirect sends a 302 to browser and browser makes separate request for new page). but you can pass message as a URL parameter or store in the session.